# implement rest html frontend PATCH

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, ejs

I'm new to this. To practice, I am currently creating a REST API with nodejs and express, with the following endpoints:

- GET site.tld/project/21 -> Show Project 21
- POST site.tld/project/33 -> Create Project 33
- PATCH site.tld/project/44 -> Change project 44
- DELETE site.tld/project/55 -> Delete project 55

etc

I want have a Website, to Show, Create, Patch and Delete Projects. So I implement the REST Client in the browser via javascript. I have built a nice frontend with Bootstrap. To send the PATCH requests from the frontend to the backend I use a script with fetch(),

Now my question:

If I want to make an HTTP PATCH or DELETE request to the API, I need the ID of the project. How do I get the ID of the project in the frontend?

I found the following possibilities:

- Get and Extract the URL with window.location.href in the frontend, since the URL of the Webpage to edit the Project contains the ID, e.g: url is "site.tld/project/33" so the ID are "33".
- I use ejs templates, I can send the ID from the backend to the frontend, and bind the data to an html data-* Tag and extract this via javascript.

None of this doesn't feel right. Can someone please explain to me what the correct way is?

Comment: Presumably if you are PATCHing a record, you are editing that record already. If that is the case, you've already fetched (GET'd) that record and it is in memory with its ID. So the workflow is generally GET -> modify in memory version -> PATCH (with ID retrieved from GET).

Comment: If you are creating a hypertext front end, then instead of thinking about "id", you should be thinking about Web Linking (RFC 8288) and uniform resource locators.

Comment: @Randy Casburn : Thanks to your answer, it brings me to the right track. It's true, before you can edit the page, the Client have to open the page. In this case, the client is already sending the ID to nodejs. So, the solution here is: in this HTTP GET Method in express (app.get('/Project/:id' .....){ }, save the ID to the "exports" Var (exports.myId = req.params.id). Then you can acces this Var inside the HTTP Patch Method.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason. How would this be look like? The Links also needs the ID, so the problem isn't solved?